# Android date.before does not work

Tags: android, android-datepicker

I have a date picker that uses DatePickerFragment.  On the onDateSet event I use the below code.

```
 DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {

        Calendar selected = Calendar.getInstance();
        selected.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        now.set(now.get(Calendar.YEAR),now.get(Calendar.MONTH),now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        if (selected.after(now) || selected.equals(now))
        {
            EditText dateField = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(Integer.valueOf(textFieldId));
            dateField.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth)
                    .append("-").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));
        }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

};
```

This code does not work, if I select todays date it still produces a toast message rather than loading the selected value into the textfield.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: `now.set` is unnecessary

Comment: Have you considered how the time portion of the two dates might affect the comparison?

Comment: Hi GreyBeardedGeek, I assumed that's what the problem was, which is why I set the date to only use Year, Month and Day, I guess I have done it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that between the moment when you select the date and when you get the "now"date happens some seconds, so the time that they both have is a little different, being now later than selected.

What you can do is only compare the fields of dayOfMonth, month and year:

```
    Calendar selected = Calendar.getInstance();
    selected.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();


    if(now.get(Calendar.YEAR)== year && now.get(Calendar.MONTH) == month && now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)== day)
    // they are the same date
```

Or you can transform both to strings using the the simple date format "dd MM yyyy"  and the compare both as a strings

Answer (score 0):

Ok Thanks to GreyBeardedGeek I was put on the right track, this is my code that works.

```
 //Set static Date for use in this fragment
Calendar todaysDate = Calendar.getInstance();
final int Year = todaysDate.get(Calendar.YEAR);
final int Month = todaysDate.get(Calendar.MONTH);
final int DayOfMonth = todaysDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

/***************** PICKER DIALOGS *****************************/
//DatePicker Dialog
private void showDatePicker(final int fieldId) {
    textFieldId = fieldId;
    DatePickerFragment date = new DatePickerFragment();
    /**
     * Set Up Current Date Into dialog
     */
    Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("year", Year);
    args.putInt("month", Month);
    args.putInt("day", DayOfMonth);
    date.setArguments(args);
    /**
     * Set Call back to capture selected date
     */
   // date.setMinimumDate(calender.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),calender.get(Calendar.MONTH),calender.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    date.setCallBack(ondate);
    date.show(getFragmentManager(), "Date Picker");

}


DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener ondate = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                          int dayOfMonth) {

       //Calendar selected = Calendar.DATE;
        Date selected =new Date(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);

       Date today = new Date(Year,Month,DayOfMonth);

        if (selected.after(today) || selected.equals(today))// (now.get(Calendar.YEAR)== year && now.get(Calendar.MONTH) == monthOfYear && now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)== dayOfMonth))
        {
            EditText dateField = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(Integer.valueOf(textFieldId));
            dateField.setText(new StringBuilder().append(dayOfMonth)
                    .append("-").append(monthOfYear + 1).append("-").append(year)
                    .append(" "));
        }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this is my Toast message!!! =)",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }

};
```